# Unit testing for React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I have a component of buttons..

```
export default class ButtonAction extends Component {

  render() {

    const { id, disabled, onClose, onSave, onRemove, isDelete } = this.props;

    return (

      <div className="footer">
        <div className="button-container">
          <button data-testid="cancel" onClick={() => onClose()}> Cancel </button>
          {
            isDelete
              ? <button data-testid="remove" disabled={!disabled} onClick={() => onRemove()} className='primary'> Yes </button>
              : <button data-testid="save" disabled={!disabled} onClick={() => onSave()} className={disabled ? 'primary' : 'disabled'}> { id ? 'Update' : 'Save' } </button>
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This is how I have made components. I am trying to do unit testing but test case does not pass..

```
test("id exists", () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<ButtonAction id={''} isDelete={false} />);
  expect(getByTestId('cancel')).toBeTruthy();
});

test("delete button exists", () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<ButtonAction id={'remove'} isDelete={true} />);

  expect(getByTestId('cancel').textContent).toBe(' Yes ')
});

test('save button exists', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<ButtonAction id={''} isDelete={false} />)

  expect(getByTestId('save').textContent).toBe(' Save ')
})

test('calling render with the same component on the same container does not remount', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<ButtonAction id={'1'} isDelete={false} />)

  expect(getByTestId('save').textContent).toBe(' Update ')
})
```

This my unit test case.. None of my test case pass.. i HAVE REFERED MY other sources but couldn't help. I am new to react.. please help me to resolve this..

```
The error below may be caused by using the wrong test environment, see jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string. Consider using the "jsdom" test environment. ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

This is the error I am getting

Comment: Did the first test case fail? What are the error messages

Comment: What is the failure messaging?

Comment: The error below may be caused by using the wrong test environment, see https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string.
    Consider using the "jsdom" test environment.

    ReferenceError: document is not defined

This is the error I am getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that the unit test environment is not `jsdom`. You must check if any global set up is used to set the test environment as `node`, in which case, a DOM would not be available for your unit tests to run.

Here is the info on the [environments](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string)

You can try to set the docblock as suggested on top of the test file and see if it works.